# SQL update of grouped data with increments

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a table with columns for an [update value], a [date], [time], [phone number], and an integer autonumber/primary key column.

I want to update the table as a set so that it groups the dates and phone numbers together (i.e., if 2 or more records have the same date and phone, then they're part of the "group") but then also puts a "1" in the earliest time record for that group, a "2" for then next earliest time record for that group, etc.

Updating with just the count of the group proved easy, but I'm hitting a wall trying to figure out how to update each group with incremental values based on the time sort.

Comment: What RDBMS/version are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2005 or 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE yt
    SET [update value] = q.RowNum
        FROM YourTable yt
            INNER JOIN (SELECT PKColumn, 
                               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [date], [phone number] ORDER BY [time]) AS RowNum
                            FROM YourTable) q
                ON yt.PKColumn = q.PKColumn;
```

You could also do this with a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
WITH cteRowNum AS (
    SELECT [update value],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTIION BY [date], [phone number] ORDER BY [time]) AS RowNum
        FROM YourTable
)
UPDATE cteRowNum
    SET [update value] = RowNum;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the ROW_NUMBER() function, e.g.

```
  SELECT
    Date,
    PhoneNumber,
    Time,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date, PhoneNumber ORDER BY Time ASC) AS IndexInGroup
  FROM
    MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

This line will create the numbers you are looking for.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [phone number], [date] ORDER BY [date] ASC) Time_Sequencer
```